# cordova Android - print from app on zebra Bluetooth printer

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, zebra-printers, bluetooth-printing

I have an app which prints some text or image using a imz320 bluetooth 
 printer.

For this, I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer

This is the function (from the plugin) that attempts to print my text:

```
    BTPrinter.list(function (data) {
        console.log("Success");
        BTPrinter.connect(function (data2) {
            console.log("Success");


            BTPrinter.print(function (data) {
                console.log("Success");


                setTimeout(function () {
                BTPrinter.disconnect(function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                    console.log(data)
                }, function (err) {
                    console.log("Error");
                    alert(err)
                    }, data[0]);
            }, 1500);

            }, function (err) {
                console.log("Error");
                alert(err);
                }, "^XA^FO10,10^AFN,26,13^FDHello, World!^FS^XZ");//base64 string, align

        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Error");
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            console.log(err)
        }, data[0])


    }, function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(err);
    })
```

I'm able to connect my device to the printer and even run the print function from my app, which gives me back a message informing me that data was sent. However, the printer does nothing (its lights turning on).

Comment: got any solution yet ?